# How to printf a fixed length output from format

Tags: c

This following code:

```
printf("%d. %-10s:", 1, "Test");
```

produces this output:

```
1. Test      :// 14 characters long
```

I would like the output length of the entire format `%d. %-10s:" to be exactly 10 characters like this:

```
1. Test:  // 10 characters
```

**Note:**

The numbers vary in length, it could be 1 or 100, so I can't deduce it's length from the output.

How can I do that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Abdul Razzak" ?

Comment: Two steps: `snprintf()` to create `"1. Test:"`, and then `printf("%-*s", 10, buffer);` where you have `char buffer[20];` and format the value into it with `snprintf()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it can't be achieved with "printf" only?

Comment: No, because `sprintf()` and `snprintf()` write formatted data to a string and you need it to go to standard output.  It could be done in two steps with `sprintf()` instead of `snprintf()`, but that's living dangerously.  With the constants in the question, it is safe enough to use `sprintf()`.  In the general case, use `snprintf()` for overflow protection (and check the return value from it too).

Comment: @razzak; Read about [`sprintf` and `snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use two steps:

```
char buffer[20];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d. %s:", 1, "Test");
printf("%-*s", 10, buffer);
```

The `snprintf()` operation give you a string `1. Test:` in `buffer`; note that it includes the `:` in the output, and assumes no trailing blanks on the string `"Test"`).  The `printf()` operation formats the string left justified (`-`) in a length of (at least) 10 (the `*` in the format and the 10 in the argument list) onto standard output.  Presumably, something else will appear after this output on the same line; otherwise, there's no obvious point to the blank padding.

For full information, see:

- [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html)

This covers the basic operation of the `*printf()` family of functions (but does not list the interfaces to the `v*printf()` or `*wprintf()` families of functions).

The code in the question and in the answer above is all done with constants.  A more realistic scenario would be:

```
void format_item(int number, const char *text, int width)
{
    char buffer[width+1];  // C99 VLA
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d. %s:", number, text);
    printf("%-*s", width, buffer);
}
```

Note that this code truncates the formatted data if the number plus the string is too long.  There are ways around that if you work a bit harder (like adding more than `1` to `width` in the definition of `buffer` — maybe add 15 instead of 1).

You might write:

```
format_item(1, "Test", 10);
```

or:

```
char *str_var = …some function call, perhaps…
int item = 56;
format_item(++item, str_var, 20);
```

etc.